# Challenge : Code Igniter , .htaccess & Subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am new bee and have been googling for last few hours but not been able to find solution to my specific problem.

Question:
I have a website developed in Code igniter framework (e.g www.example.com).
On the website, i have got each user's profile.The url for individual user profile looks like this:

www.example.com/users/profile/chris

www.example.com/users/profile/david

www.example.com/users/profile/james

and so on..

At the moment , I am using **www.domain.com/controller/method/id** Code igniter URL pattern .

Now, i want to map individual profiles into sub domains. I want to provide each user an individual sub domain so that they could jump to their profile instantly like this:

www.chris.example.com

www.david.example.com

www.james.example.com

Is this something that can be achieved in Code igniter and .htaccess?

If yes then what steps i would need to follow (for .htaccess / code igniter)?

I would appreciate if anybody could help as i am badly stuck..Thanks

Comment: Would the subdomains be dynamically created?

Comment: Thanks .manually on my web host.

Comment: So every time someone registers, you would create a subdomain manually? I wouldn't bother but following @t0tallynotdave answer pretty much sums up CodeIgniter's capabilities for this scenario..

Answer (score 2):

Not easily - don't try and mess about with dynamic subdomains if you're new to any of this. Plus, with subdomains come problems with remaining logged in site-wide (yes, it's possible but not nice to implement.)
You're better off sticking with changing CodeIgniter routes.php (see documentation [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)) to manipulate URIs e.g instead of having **/users/profile/james** go to james' profile, you could add a route to route **/u/[name]** to the **users/profile** method.